# Using callout[] to create a plane

Tags: complex, labeling

I want to create a plane that represents $15$ powers of complex number: $a$<sub>1</sub> $= (10/7)*(Cos(Pi/10) + i*Sin(Pi/10)) $. I also want to label the points with the text "a to power k" where $k$ will be the power I elevate $a$. The axes need to be labeled as $R$ for Real and $I$ for imaginary part of number. This is what I have

```
a1 = (10/7)*(Cos[Pi/10] + I*Sin[Pi/10]);
valuesa1 = Table[a1^k, {k, 0, 12}];
N[valuesa1]
ListPlot[Table[Callout[a1^k], {k, 0, 12}], AxesLabel -> {R, I}]
```

My goal is to observe the points corresponding to the consecutive powers of the complex number. However, for some reason, not all the points are present on the graph.

Comment: `a1 = (10/7)*(Cos[Pi/10] + I*Sin[Pi/10]);
valuesa1 = Table[a1^k, {k, 0, 12}];
ListPlot[Table[Callout[ReIm[a1^k], k], {k, 0, 12}], 
 AxesLabel -> {R, I}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html):

```
a1 = (10/7)*(Cos[Pi/10] + I*Sin[Pi/10]);

ComplexListPlot[Table[Callout[a1^k, k], {k, 0, 12}], 
   AxesLabel -> {R, I}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If you use `Callout[N @ a1^k]` instead of `Callout[a1^k, k]` you get:

[image]

Comment: Hello, that is an interesting command. I'll look it up and explore the command a bit further because it's something I haven't seen yet